# Store tooltip for a control in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Platform: C#.Net

Hi,
    I am trying to store the tooltip for a control in a variable, but didn't achieve any result for that yet. Any suggestions?

Here is the code I have tried so far,

```
var tooltip = new ToolTip();
           var tool1 =  tooltip.GetToolTip(HCp10);
           MessageBox.Show(tool1);
```

Comment: How do you mean store?

Comment: I want to store it in a variable for further use...

Comment: I think storing the tooltips text only would be enough? Why not use a string?

Comment: I tried doing that but it shows blank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to know the tooltip for a control, you could set the control's tag to the tooltip

```
Control c = new Control();
ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
c.Tag = t;

Tooltip t = (ToolTip)c.Tag;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code:) I got another way like this also it works :
 

var tooltip = toolTipHCP.GetToolTip(HCp10);
Where, Hcp10 is the control name...

Comment: So, I have one doubt from your code, How do I get a particular control's tooltip from the code that you have mentioned?

Comment: @Harsh, the above posted code, does not provide an answer for your question.